# How to use messageListWithFetchAttributes in MailCore for iOS?

Tags: mailcore

As the title mention,there is no document nor example for this function.Can anyone show me the way how to use it?
FYI,I want to get the messages with attributes,something like messages with uid larger than xxxx.Thx for Advanced.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you getting errors? People aren't likely to just give you the code you need. Help us help you.

Comment: Yes,I tried,but I can't find the way.If you look inside the code,you will see the parameter (NSArray *)attributes is ingore,for my understanding this function can't get Messages with atrributes.But at the same time I search the answer on the net,I find https://github.com/mronge/MailCore/issues/14 and https://github.com/mronge/MailCore/issues/5 .So I think this function works in some way I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use `messageListWithFetchAttributes` to get all the messages,then sort the list with uid, then I can get the messages with uid larger than xxxxx.Even it is not an efficient way,but it works.